# SFML code completion not working for Code::Blocks 13.12 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, sfml, code-completion

EDIT: NOT WORKING ON ANY IDE, SEEMS TO BE A GENERAL MISCONFIG

So hello guys. It's taking a bit longer to set my Ubuntu system to code with SFML and C++ than expected. This should be one of the last problems really.

So my C::B 13.12 install via apt-get on Ubuntu 14.04 will auto-complete all of my code perfectly, standard libs and personal .h files included. But it seems to be failing at auto-completing SFML. At least the .hpp files are found and C::B will give me some suggestions, like with any other .h files, but not the same thing happens with the classes and structs. To be concrete, this happens. Whenever I include the SFML files to a program, and try get code suggestions from the sf namespace, this happens.

[image: As you can see, only some trivial types appear, not the SFML classes.]

Sorry for that image, but on screen shot the suggestions close. The types suggested are Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, and their Uint types.

So well, I can't really think of anything else to do. These are my Search paths for my GNU GCC Compiler on C::B.

[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot guys! 
Peace.

Comment: This is more of a problem with Codeblocks in general since its autocomplete stuff has always been dodgy for me as well.

Comment: @Poriferous I know, I have also heard installing a nightly build would help me, but I wanna see if there is something a bit user friendlier to do. On Windows, SFML code completion works out of the box, but here on Linux it seems to be failing... Going back to Windows is not an option by now.

Comment: You could always use Qt Creator or Kdevelop. Both provide good support for auto-completion. WIth the latter you have to use CMake, and on the former qmake which is a Qt abstraction of CMake.

Comment: @Poriferous I'm working on a team, and well, we are all using C::B by now. Is there a way of me using the .cbp files on Kdevelop?

Comment: No. Kdevelop uses its own format for reading projects. I'm also CodeBlocks 13.12 and SFML parses fine when I type sf::. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Poriferous Strange, it's not working on KDevelop either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libsfml-dev reinstall was enough.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I am actually the author. That's the answer to my problem.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems if this is the answer to your own question "accept" you own answer, or just make an **update** inside the question, just to keep everything inline

Comment: @Ethaan Takes two days for me to be able to accept the question.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems roger thath

Answer (score 2):

In Code::Blocks try right click on project — «Reparse this project». 
That helped me — maybe it'll help you too.